# I want to read a string with multiple names and match them with names in a list Python

Tags: python, string-matching, fuzzywuzzy

In Python I receive a string of surnames and last names so for instance "Jmes Mai, Richard Hammond  Jrmy Clarkson". These are user input so I cannot verify if they will be separated with a comma or spelled correctly. Users can also fill in as many names as they want. Furthermore I have a list with +- 200 names in it of people the user can pick.

What I want to do now is make a list of these names from the large list that are the best match with the user picked names. So in the above example, I want the output to be [James May, Richard Hammond, Jeremy Clarkson] (Given that these exist in the large list of names.)

So far I have tried cutting the string in all possible substrings. and using the process.extract from the fuzzywuzzy package to brute force this problem in a way where all the substrings are matched and put in a list. After this duplicates are removed. The problem with this is it gives a lot of false positives and takes a really long time so I was wondering if there was a better way to do it.

Thank you in advance!

```
def match_names(s):
    lst = []
    for name in names:
        for tup in process.extract(name.lower(), options(s)):
            if tup[1] > 95:
                if name not in lst:
                    lst.append(name)
    return lst
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of `Levenshtein` distance?

Comment: To add to @ombk's suggestion, here's a nice [article](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-build-an-autocorrect-in-python-7545338a1320) written by [George Pipis](https://jorgepit-14189.medium.com) on how to build an autocorrect in Python.

Comment: @ombk yes I have thought of this and it does about the same as the process.extract function. The issues lie in the implementation around the string matching algorithm. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Try using difflib library and import get_close_matches as followed :

```
from difflib import get_close_matches
for i, j in zip(len(name), len(lst)):
    if len(get_close_matches(name,lst[i])>0):
        'Do what ever you wish here'
```

Comment: I don't understand what name is supposed to be in this instance. The point is there are several names in one string. Furthermore taking the range of a string and a list is not possible in Python. Do you mean the length of the list and names string?

Comment: yea my bad, try it out now. I gave you a direction so you can think about the answer in your instance yourself.